# Given a probability space, show that the following are equivalent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, X a random variable, and $\tilde{X}: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1] $ defined by $\tilde{X}(s)= P(X \leq s) $ is the distribution function. Prove that the following are equivalent:

$(1) \tilde{X}$ is continous on $\mathbb{R}$
$(2) \tilde{X}$ is uniformly continous on $\mathbb{R}$
$(3)P(X=t)=0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$
$(4)(\tilde{X} \circ X)\tilde{ }(s) = s$ for every $s \in \mathbb{R}$

I think I understand $(1) \implies (2) \implies(3)$ but I'm having trouble with $(3) \implies (4)$ and $(4) \implies (1)$. The notation in $(4)$ is a bit confusing to me but I think we have $(\tilde{X} \circ X)\tilde{ }(s)= P[\{x:P(\{y : X(y) \leq X(x)\}) \leq s\}]$ and I'm not sure where to go form here.

Comment: Are you sure about $s\in \mathbb{R}$ in (4)? With the natural parsing of the question, there is no way one can have $s= \tilde{X}\circ\tilde{X}(s) \in[0,1]$ is $s\notin[0,1]$.

Comment: That is how it is written in Axler's new book on measure theory, but yes I think it's really supposed to be $0$ if $s < 0$, $s$ if $s \in [0,1]$, and $1$ if $s > 1$.